# Parsing XML into wx.Python RichTextCtrl

Tags: xml, wxpython, richtextbox

I'm trying to display some text in a wx.Python RichTextCtrl, but I get an error:

```
XML parsing error: 'not well-formed (invalid token)' at line 1
```

The irony is that the xml was generated by the RichTextXMLHandler. My code is:

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import objectify

class DisplayXML(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(DisplayXML, self).__init__(parent)

    self.InitUI()
    self.SetTitle('Display XML')
    self.Layout()
    self.Fit()
    self.Center()
    self.Show()
    self.DisplayRTF()

  def InitUI(self):
    self.txtRTF=rt.RichTextCtrl(self, size=(650,275), style=wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL);
  mainSizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
  mainSizer.Add(self.txtRTF)
  self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
  self.InputXML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + \
                  '<richtext version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.wxwidgets.org">' + \
                    '<paragraphlayout textcolor="#4C4C4C" fontsize="11" fontstyle="90"' + \
                        'fontweight="90" fontunderlined="0" fontface="Ubuntu" alignment="1"' + \
                        'parspacingafter="10" parspacingbefore="0" linespacing="10">' + \
                            '<paragraph alignment="2">' + \
                              '<text>Centred text</text>' + \
                      '</paragraph>' + \
                    '</paragraphlayout>' + \
                  '</richtext>'

  def DisplayRTF(self):
    rtfXML=self.InputXML

    #print rtfXML
    #root = objectify.fromstring(rtfXML)
    #print root.paragraphlayout.paragraph.getchildren()[0]

    out = StringIO()
    handler=wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler()
    buffer=self.txtRTF.GetBuffer()
    buffer.AddHandler(handler)
    out.write(rtfXML)
    out.seek(0)
    handler.LoadStream(buffer, out)
    self.txtRTF.Refresh()

    self.txtRTF.SetValue(self.InputXML)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  DisplayXMLApp=wx.App()
  DisplayXML(None)
  DisplayXMLApp.MainLoop()
```

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: If no one can help, can anyone point me to an example that shows how this might work? Thanks

Comment: OK. Having tried elimination, the token that the parser objects to is 'alignment="1"'. If I remove this the rtbox displays. Can anyone suggest why? This xml was generated by the RichTextXMLHandler

Comment: I was wrong. the issue has been solved by making sure the xml code is converted to string data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. the issue has been solved by making sure the xml code is converted to string data type

Answer (score 0):

What line specifically in your code throws the error?

Comment: It wasn't a line, I just got an error dialog box - very frustrating